# use of interrogatives in the clause

Tags: questions, run-on-sentence

I have a point of confusion regarding the use of interrogatives in English, as I am not a native speaker of English.

> **I want you to inquire from your teacher of English that are the classes of English punctuation going on or not?**

In the above sentence, I think I have made a run-on sentence. Am I right? Or is the sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: A run-on sentence is two independent clauses with no connectors between them:  "It's a beautiful day I'm going to the beach."  Try this:  "Please ask your English teacher if punctuation classes are still going on."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a run-on sentence, but it's not grammatically correct. A run-on sentence would typically have multiple subjects and predicates all strung together, frequently with commas or no punctuation at all, where each clause "runs into" the next. You are communicating a thought that *can* be expressed as a proper sentence; it just needs a little work.

Try this:

> I want you to **ask** your **English** teacher **whether** the classes **about** English punctuation **are** going on or not.

Key changes are highlighted in bold. In particular note:

- "inquire" is more formal; "ask" is much more common. You can use "inquire" here and it would be grammatical, but it's very wordy (uses more words than necessary to communicate the idea clearly).
- "your teacher of English" and "the classes of English punctuation" are *technically* correct, but most native English speakers wouldn't use this construction. This sounds more like how it would be said in Spanish (*tu maestra de ingles*). In English, the preference is to put the adjective before the noun for these simple cases. Note that I have offered another option (*the classes **about** English punctuation*) in the example above, using a more natural-sounding preposition.
- "whether" is preferable to "that" in this instance. Use your favorite grammar book to do a little research on *relative pronouns* for more info. Also note that using the relative pronoun to introduce the dependent clause (basically, all the words after "that" in your original sentence) means that you need to move the verb (*are*) to its standard place after the subject noun phrase.
- Because the core concept here is "I want you to ask your teacher something," it's not really a question. So the correct end punctuation is a period, not a question mark.

Final note: We are happy to help, but you may find that the [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) is a more useful resource for these types of questions.

Best wishes!

EDIT: A comment on the original question suggested the following revision:

> Please ask your English teacher if (the) punctuation classes are still going on.

This is certainly more natural and the way that I would say it myself. I am leaving my original analysis above because I was attempting to change as few words as possible and articulate the reason for each edit. But this is a good revision and is worthy of note. (H/T deadrat)

Comment: Well, I am impressed by the quality of your answer. I want to ask one other question. Is it okay use question mark with the descriptive constructions of interrogative? In the above sentence, you haven't changed the order of the sentence and used question mark in the end.

Comment: @UmerMalik Excellent point! No, it should be a period at the end, not a question mark. As you no doubt correctly deduced, the core concept of this sentence is "I want you to ask your teacher something." So it's not really a question. The exception would be if you were *quoting* a question, but then the question mark would be inside the quotation marks (Please ask your teacher, "When are the classes?"). I will update my answer to correct the punctuation error. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it is because of confidence your answer has given to me. I have plenty of questions regarding English Grammar, and I don't have the source to consult. Would it be okay to ask in the comment box? At a given moment, I just have only two questions in my mind.

Comment: Once you have 20 reputation you can participate in Chat, which might be a good forum for general unstructured questions/discussions. Ask them here (in the comments) for now, and we can either answer them in the comments or perhaps even open one or more new questions if they are of interest to the general community.

Comment: I hope I will earn 20 reputations soon. Well, the question is the following: do we use the indefinite article with the word, which comes before the uncountable noun--such as "I need an additional information"?

Comment: No. If it's uncountable you can either omit the indefinite article ("I need additional information"), use a definite article, assuming that it fits your intended meaning ("I need the additional information"), or use a measurement and then move the object into a prepositional phrase ("I need a piece of additional information").

Comment: That means I have the option either to omit the indefinite article or to use the definite article.

Comment: Any of those three options I listed are valid. Just depends on the shade of meaning you are looking for. If you are considering using an indefinite article, then the first option ("I need additional information") is probably what you want (and in general is the most commonly heard variant).

Answer (score 3):

The word "that" is grammatically incorrect.

> I want you to inquire from your teacher of English, "Are the
> classes of English punctuation going on or not?"

---

Using "of" is unnatural, but makes sense.

> teacher of English --> English teacher
>
> classes of English punctuation --> English punctuation classes

---

Here is a more natural version:

> I want you to ask your English teacher, "Are the English punctuation
> classes going on or not?"

Here, the main clause is in the indicative mood.

- I want you to ask your English teacher.

The **interrogative clause** is a dependent clause being used as a [direct object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28grammar%29#Syntactic_category).

- I want you to ask your English teacher ***something***.
- *something = "Are the English punctuation classes going on or not?"*

---

If you use a dependent word like "that", the dependent clause cannot be in the interrogative.

Also, "that" doesn't work with "or not". You need "whether" or "if".

> I want you to inquire from your English teacher **whether** the English
> punctuation classes are going on **or not**.
>
> I want you to inquire from your English teacher **if** the English
> punctuation classes are going on **or not**.

These clauses are in the indicative mood, not the interrogative.  They are "indicating" that you want something.

Comment: Your answer has provided me with the additional information; it has cleared my remaining doubts or confusions, Sir.